# Can't access windows 10 after ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I am new to Ubuntu. I was already having Windows 10 on my pc. Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, it run quite well. But when I restart my pc then I directly got Ubuntu with no grub window for selection between Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Install Synaptic packet manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

search and check if all needed Grub 2 packages are selected/updated.

Comment: It did'nt work.